# Tools similar to Local Website Archive (by Aignesberger Software)

Tags: web, information-management, web-browser

I am looking for a tool to archive single web pages similar to  [Local Website Archive](https://www.aignes.com/lwa.htm). My problem with the latter is that it uses IE as its internal engine and some pages do not get saved properly.

The tools would preferably keep all pages in one single file. You should be able to browse the different saved pages on a tree-structured folder interface. Page titles would be extracted automatically from the URL.